# Nested if statement execution error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a nested-if statement in shell script. Script is given below.

```
#select the snapshot or release    
if  [ "$SELECT_SNAP_OR_REL_VERSION" == "Snapshots" ]
then
    $SELECT_SNAPSHOT_VERSION
    echo "Snapshot Selected"

elif [ "$SELECT_SNAP_OR_REL_VERSION" == "Releases" ] 
then
     $SELECT_RELEASE_VERSION
     echo "Release Selected"

     if [ "$Server_Selection" == "192.168.94.139" ]
     then
         selectDevSnap;
         echo "deployed to 139"

     elif [ "$Server_Selection" == "192.168.94.140" ]
     then
         selectProdRel
         echo "deployed to 140"

      else 
          echo "ERROR"

      fi

else 
      echo "Error Selection"
fi
```

In this script only execute "192.168.94.140" section. How can I correct this?

Comment: Try `set -x` to see what happens.

Comment: Why did you start another question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483119/parse-arguments-one-script-to-another ?

Comment: What are  the values of the involved variables?

Comment: @RalfFriedl Previously I did'nt have an idea how to combine those two scripts. But I tried and got an answer, in here I got an error in the script.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
relVersion="$SELECT_RELEASE_VERSION_ARTIFACT_URL" 

snapVersion="$SELECT_SNAPSHOT_VERSION_ARTIFACT_URL"         

source=(/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Proj_Frontend_Parameterized_Deployment/*.tgz) 

selectDevSnap(){

           devDestination=(proj@192.168.94.139:/usr/share/nginx/PROJFRONTEND/proj.com/)

           wget "$snapVersion"
           scp $source $devDestination
           ssh proj@192.168.94.139 "cd /usr/share/nginx/PROJFRONTEND/proj.com/ ; tar xvf *.tgz"

            }


selectProdRel(){

           prodDestination=(proj@192.168.94.140:/usr/share/nginx/PROJFRONTEND/proj.com/)

           wget "$relVersion"
           scp $source $prodDestination
           ssh proj@192.168.94.140 "cd /usr/share/nginx/PROJFRONTEND/proj.com/ ; tar xvf *.tgz"

            }

             if  [ "$SELECT_SNAP_OR_REL_VERSION" == "Snapshots" ]
            then
                   $SELECT_SNAPSHOT_VERSION
                   echo "Snapshot Selected"

                if [ "$SELECT_SNAP_OR_REL_VERSION" == "Releases" ] 
                then
                   $SELECT_RELEASE_VERSION
                   echo "Release Selected"
                fi

                if [ "$Server_Selection" == "192.168.94.139" ]
                then
                    selectDevSnap;
                    echo "deployed to 139"

                elif [ "$Server_Selection" == "192.168.94.140" ]
                then
                   selectProdRel
                   echo "deployed to 140"

                else 
                   echo "ERROR"

                fi

            else 
                echo "Error Selection"

            fi
```

Comment: Sure, but we still don't know what `$SELECT_RELEASE_VERSION` is (it's treated as code here), or what any of the other variables are.  It's hard to debug a program when you don't know what it looks like and under what data it takes to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Yeah, But I am working on Jenkins Deployment Project. $SELECT_RELEASE_VERSION is the variable I assigned into a plugin